# How do I view an image that I just took in android development?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I'm new to android development and I'm falling flat when it comes down to figuring out fundamentals like viewing and saving a picture I just took with the camera app. So far this is my code for getting to the camera app

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and this is my incomplete OnActivityResult() method

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    ImageView rondo = null;
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
   rondo.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

And this is my layout for this activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >




    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageViewName" 
                        android:layout_width="90dp" 
                        android:layout_height="90dp" 
                        android:scaleType="fitStart" 
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
                        android:padding="10dp" 
                        />
                        />

     </LinearLayout>
```

I'm trying to get the image I took and put in the spot I've specified in the layout, as shown by the ImageView. However, my app keeps crashing after I take a picture. I don't know what I'm doing so any advice is helpful

Comment: We need the stack trace from logcat to help.  Please edit your question and include it.

Answer (score 0):

Exception you might be getting here is `NullPointerException`

Inside your `OnActivityResult()` method you have a `ImageView rondo` referenced to `null` then you are trying to call setImageBitmap() from that null referenced variable. So it is obviously `NullPointerException`

To get rid of that you could do the following,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView rondo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewName);
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
   rondo.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);

    }
```

> Hope that helps!!!!!!!!!!!!!